# How can I turn a tile map to bunch of bounding boxes?

Tags: c#, xna, bounding-box

I'm trying to do collision detection with xna.
I have a (kind-of) platformer map that I draw a map from an 2d array like this:

```
  int[,] map = new int[,] 
{
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
};
```

I took it from http://xnatd.blogspot.com/2009/02/ok-so-first-part-of-our-tower-defence.html so it's not the actual one but it's similiar. I also have a class for my main charecter like a side-scroller that has bounding box with no problems.

However, how can I get bounding boxes of my tile-set and check if mario.boundingbox intersects with them?

I know that I can use `boundingbox.intersects(boundingbox2)` for intersection but there are going to be many bounding boxes (maybe a 2d array of them? is this possible?) and I have tried a few times yet I messed up.

The code I use to draw is very similiar to the one in the link. I have tried to make a boundingbox array and set a bounding box for them since I know both x,y and sizes but I ended up creating bounding boxes on random spots.

I think I need to know how can I create bounding boxes within this code and use them later(loop throuogh every x and y see if anything touches?):

```
for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        int textureIndex = map[y, x];
        if (textureIndex == -1)
            continue;

        Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];
        batch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(
            x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
    }
}
```

I'd be glad to learn if there is another way to do this or my thinking is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would try to NOT have any game logic without your Draw() calls as when XNA detects the game is running slowly, it will ignore Draw() until the Update() calls have caught up.

The obvious drawback of this, for you, is that if for some reason the game runs slowly (i.e. user has bad hardware), the collision detection won't even happen! Obviously not good =P

A general approach would be to get your players position in terms of the array/grid, and loop over the surrounding squares of the array to check to see if there is a 1 in that space, if there is, create a collision rectangle for it and see if it intersects with the player; I'll try write some code for you:

```
for (int i = player.X - 1; i < player.X + 2; i++) // Check in a 3x3 square with player in middle
{
    for (int j = player.Y - 1; j < player.Y + 2; j++)
    {
        if (map[i, j] == 1)
        {
            // Make rectangle, check for collision, do logic if there is one
        }
    }
}
```

You would want this in your update block, you would also want to make sure i and j don't go out of bounds of the grid.

**EDIT:**

Now that I think about it, recreating all of the rectangles on every update call is probably a bad idea. You may be better doing a check when the player attempts to move to see if he's going to be walking into a square that has a '1' in the array - and then adjust/cancel the movement accordingly.